# Setup maven pom to work with dependencies across environments

Tags: maven

I have a Java projects `a-1.0.jar` with `ojdbc.jar` dependency and `b.jar` that depends on `a-1.0.jar` and `ojdbc.jar`. I am trying to make it work on my machine, new user machine and a Bamboo server.

Desired behavior:
On local machine `git clone <git_url>`, `mvn clean install`, `java -jar b.jar` project should run.  Bamboo should checkout and run project.
On Bamboo: a plan can check out a project and run it. Build should track version of `b.jar` built and `a.jar` used.

So far I saw these  options:
 `<systemPath>${project.basedir}/lib/a-1.0.jar</systemPath>`: maven warns that it will fail to resolve dependencies
A Perl script to run  `mvn install` for each dependent jar before building the project
(1) defeats the purpose of DevOps automation
(2) makes it unclear which version of a jar was used
(3) installs the jar, but `java -jar b.jar` fails `a.jar` is missing

I can overcome this with another Perl script that adds the dependent jars to a classpath

These are basic tasks and as a build tool Maven should be able to do it.

How to tell Maven to three goals below?
(1) For each unknown import - get a jar from lib folder
(2) Make a set of dependent jars. That is don't import `ojdbc` twice
(3) Pack a self sufficient jar that runs, not fails with "stuff is missing"

Comment: Start using a repository manager and install such deps which do not exist in central there. Afterwards you can use them as usual dependencies..and makes handling easier....also on CI server (Bamboo)...

Comment: @khmarbaise  This is not an option. Our organization is going through DevOps'ification that takes forever. Some parts of our company have access to artifactory, but my office doesn't. But management wants to have local and Bamboo builds ASAP. Can maven get jars from Git?

Comment: If that's not an option. That's really bad cause using a repository manager is the simplest option...And no Maven does not consume jars' from Git cause Git is a version control tool and not a repository manager....

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you need to create an executable jar - and for this, you can use various approaches.

One of them is, add [maven-shade-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/examples/executable-jar.html) which puts all dependencies into single jar, while taking care of potential resource collisions.

Comment: Unfortunatelly, shade can't import dependency jars if these dependencies aren't in maven central. Also,  it complains if the same dependency was shaded in `a.jar` and `b.jar`. +1 for the help though.

Answer (score 0):

Try non-maven-jar-maven plugin. It adds jars that are not in the maven central.